# Asking opinion about multipe inheritance

Tags: php, class, object, inheritance

My mentor said that,

My current `developing project` needs `session object` at all times.
`Bulletin controller` and `User controller` also need `session object` at all times.
That means, It's better that it has `Super(Parent) Class` for your current `developing project`.
`"Super Class"` doesn't mean a `Controller_Base` which is already exists.

Well, `PHP` or `Java` can not do `"Multiple inheritance"` like below.

```
------------------------------
class Controller_Bulletin extends Controller_Base, Controller_Application
------------------------------
```

It will error occur.

If you were me, what do you think you would have to do?
I'm confused and need some advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can better implement this using a softer form of **Dependency Injection** and not multiple inheritance (which is not possible in PHP).

Just give each class that needs it a specific instance of your Session object during initialization.

```
class MyClass {

    protected $session;

    public function __construct($stuff) { ... }

    public function setSession($session) {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

}

$myObject = new MyClass();
$myObject->setSession($session);
$myObject->doSomeStuff();
```

Another method that tries to solve the problem of multiple inheritance in PHP is Traits.
You can add some functionality to a multitude of classes with these. In my oppinion, Dependency Injection is a far better method though.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php